# App engine URL not found on server when there is a dot in the URL

Tags: vue.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am using GCP App engine to host my Vue application. And in this application, I have a dynamic route defined as `/imp/:id/:email/:type`. In the email parameter I have a valid email with the format `john@gmail.com`. This type of request to the server is returning `The requested URL /imp/****/john@gmail.com/gm was not found on this server.` When I remove the `.` in the email the request is directed to the server correctly. My app.yaml is defined as follows:

```
runtime: nodejs14
service: frontend-app
handlers:
  # Serve all static files with urls ending with a file extension
- url: /(.*\..+)$ 
  static_files: dist/\1
  upload: dist/(.*\..+)$
  # catch all handler to index.html
- url: /.*
  static_files: dist/index.html
  upload: dist/index.html
```

I am using other workarounds like moving the email to a query parameter now but I would like to understand how I can fix this. Thank you,

Comment: A URL with a dot will be processed by the static file handler.

Comment: @googlecloudsucks Okay, I see. Are there any other workarounds to direct these kinds of requests to the file?

Comment: You need to change your URL scheme.  I use `/static` for static files.  Instead you could use extensions: `/.*\.(jpg|png)`

Comment: If your problem is solved post the solution as an answer,
it will be helpful for others who are facing the similar issue